# Index of specific loaded userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have many instances of the same userform loaded at the same time.

Each of them has a button.

What I need to do is to get the index of the userform that I clicked it's button.

This is my approach so far but I get an error referring to line no. 6

```
Public Function UserFormInstance(ByVal objTargetUserForm As Object) As Long
    Dim strUserFormName As String

    For Each objUserForm In VBA.UserForms
        strUserFormName = objTargetUserForm.Name

        If objUserForm.Name = strUserFormName Then
            UserFormInstance = UserFormInstance + 1

            If objUserForm = objTargetUserForm Then '==> Here is the problem
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next objUserForm

    Set objUserForm = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xxx As Long
    xxx = UserFormInstance Me
    MsgBox xxx
End Sub
```

I need your help please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparing Objects, you need to use `Is` instead of `=`:

```
If objUserForm Is objTargetUserForm Then
    Exit For
End If
```

(You are probably already used to doing this with the special Object `Nothing`, e.g. `If objUserForm Is Nothing Then`, etc)

Comment: Wow.. that was so easy! Thank you so much.